# "И в шутку и всерьез"

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно

Почему "в шутку" пишется раздельно, а "всерьез" - слитно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слово "шутка" — литературное, а слово "серьёз" — просторечное..